# Convert bibtex entry to another data type

Tags: haskell

I want to conver [bibtex entry](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bibtex/0.0.6.1/doc/html/Text-BibTeX-Entry.html) into my own custom data type, which looks something like:

```
date MyEntry = MyEntry {
    ident :: String,
    author :: [String],
    address :: String
}
```

But fields like `author` and `address` are stored in the bibtex's fields array:

```
data T =
Cons {
   entryType :: String,
   identifier :: String,
   fields :: [(String, String)]
}
deriving (Show)
```

An example of the above would be something like:

> Cons {entryType = "Book", identifier = "Arrighi", fields = [("author",
>   "Arrighi, Gino"),("title","Leonardo Fibonacci : La Pratica di
>   Geometria. (Volgar izzata da Cristofano di Gherardo di Dino, cittadino
>   pisano. Dal Codice 2186 dell a Biblioteca Riccardiana di Firenze.) / A
>   cura e con introduzione di Gino Arrigh
>   i."),("address","Pisa"),("publisher","Domus
>   Galilaeana"),("date","1966"),("note" ,"(Testimonianze di storia della
>   scienza, 3)"),("language","italian"),("pagetota
>   l","234"),("hyphenation","italian")]}

How can I pattern match on it to convert it to my data type?

I got stuck immediately (this doesn't work):

```
toEntry  Cons { @entryType, @ident, @fields } = toEntry' entryType' ident fields'

toEntry' entryType ident fs = MyEntry { ident, entryType, ???????? }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pattern match on records as described by @ehird, but I think you have also asked about how to convert "fields" list into your "author" and "address" fields.

You can use standard Prelude function "lookup" for this. It works as follows:

```
lookup :: k -> [(k, v)] -> Maybe v
lookup "a" [("a", 1), ("b", 2)] = Just 1
lookup "c" [("a", 1), ("b", 2)] = Nothing
```

It may return "Nothing" if key is not found or "Just value" otherwise.

So you may convert between these two data types with something like this:

```
convert :: T -> MyEntry
convert (Cons e i fields) = MyEntry i [auth] addr
  where auth = fromMaybe "" (lookup "author" fields)
        addr = fromMaybe "" (lookup "address" fields)
```

Here, you convert Nothing into an empty string, which is generally not a good idea. Therefore, you may need to change type of address from "String" to "Maybe String" to consider the fact that address may be missing from the original fields.

Moreover, you may have experience problems with multiple authors, since "lookup" returns the first matching key's value and that's all. To handle multiple "author" fields, you may either write your custom lookup function or convert fields list into a Data.Map, concatenating the values of the same key. Here is how (I have changed address type to list, in order to allow multiple addresses as well):

```
data MyEntry = MyEntry {
    ident :: String,
    author :: [String],
    address :: [String]
}

convert :: T -> MyEntry
convert (Cons e i fields) = MyEntry i auth addr
  where
    fieldsMap = fieldsToMap fields
    auth = lookupField "author" fieldsMap
    addr = lookupField "address" fieldsMap

-- lookup field and return an empty list if not found
lookupField :: String -> Map.Map String [String] -> [String]
lookupField = Map.findWithDefault []

-- convert each value into a list and then turn into a map,
-- concatenating values with the same keys
fieldsToMap :: [(String, String)] -> Map.Map String [String]
fieldsToMap = Map.fromListWith (++) . map (\ (k, v) -> (k, [v]))
```

Comment: No worries about multiple authors. Also thanks - I think I'll change my type to have `Maybe String` instead of just `String` everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You pattern match on a record in the same way you write a record literal, only using patterns instead of expressions: `Constructor { field1 = pat, field2 = pat, ... }`. For example:

```
toEntry Cons{entryType=et, identifier=i, fields=fs} = toEntry' et i fs

toEntry' et i fs = MyEntry { ident = ..., author = ..., address = ... }
```

You can also use standard constructor syntax with records. In this case, it might be clearer to omit the helper function, and use the standard syntax instead:

```
toEntry (Cons et i fs) = MyEntry (...) (...) (...)
```

Another option is to use [record puns](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-puns) (with `{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}`), which let you omit the pattern (or expression, in record literals), binding the field to its name:

```
toEntry Cons{entryType, identifier, fields} = ...
```

Additionally, since you're binding all the fields, you can use [record wildcards](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-wildcards) (`{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}`), which simply bind all the fields to their names:

```
toEntry Cons{..} = ...
```

However, in this case, there are few enough fields that the plain constructor syntax seems fine to me, and I generally dislike record puns, since they shadow the field accessors (which have the same name as the fields).

Comment: What what about the key-value pairs in the fields array? I can't construct `MyEntry` half-way and then process those...

Comment: Well, you asked about pattern matching :) For converting the fields, see dying_sphynx's answer.